# CSS: Positioning images in a Div

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm looking to position images over top of a div which has a set background.  I'm using CSS to style the div as well as the images sitting on top of the background but I'm not seeing the results that I'd expect.  The images which are sitting on top of the div's background image does not adjust based on my pixel settings.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="colorpicker" id="colorpicker">
    <img src="images/color_unselected.png" class="unselected" />
    <img src="images/color_C.png" class="c_image" />
    <img src="images/color_K.png" class="k_image" />
    <img src="images/color_M.png" class="m_image" />
    <img src="images/color_Y.png" class="y_image" />
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```css
#colorpicker{
    border: 0px;
    width: 63;
    height: 342;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-left: 1002px;
    background-image: url(images/color_tab_container.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#colorpicker.unselected{
    top: 50px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Paste your code, select it using mouse and then click on `{}` icon on the menubar of editor.

Comment: Are you trying to put all the images overlapping one another, or do you mean to show one of the images based on user selection of cyan, magenta, yellow, black, none?

Comment: edit your post and put in correct tags please...

Comment: Basically I want the color images to be stacked (column) with a space in between each one.  I should have put all of the css in but only put the unselected portion in for examples sake.

Comment: Your images should be put below each other if the div width is not large enough to hold two images. You could apply margin-top:[x]px; to get some space in between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't make up from your question how exactly you want to position those four images, but I would make a selector for your images and not the parent div:

*html:*

```
<div class="colorpicker" id="colorpicker">
  <img src="images/color_unselected.png" class="unselected">
  <img src="images/color_C.png" id="c_image" class="image" />
  <img src="images/color_K.png" id="k_image" class="image" />
  <img src="images/color_M.png" id="m_image" class="image" />
  <img src="images/color_Y.png" id="y_image" class="image" />
</div>
```

*css:*

```
img.image {
  /*whatever you want to do here*/
}
#colorpicker {
  border: 0px;
  width: 63;
  height: 342;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-left: 1002px;
  background-image: url(images/color_tab_container.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#colorpicker.unselected{ top: 50px; right: 25px; }
```

Sidenote: you can just type/copy-paste the code here, select in and press the above 'code sample' button. This will display it correctly as you see above (make sure you do this for html and css separately) :-)

Answer (score 0):

To get the images to "stack", with a margin between then, add the following CSS:

```
#colorpicker img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/KX5mS/ for a working example.